# How much does GPA of individial subjects matter for PhD admissions

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

How much does GPA matter for PhD admission? Just came to know that I scored a passing grade in statistics, still managed to score 45 percentile though.

I scored perfect gpa in stats physics though.

Was wondering what kind of impression it makes and will it affect my chances to get into a good grade school!

Answer (score 1):

No single thing is likely to be determinative of graduate admissions. Committees will look at a lot of things including your GPA. They want to make a prediction about your likelihood of success in their program and thereafter. Grades in the subject of study are important, but a single grade might be ignored. What courses you did well in probably has more effect as well as required standardized tests. Letters of recommendation are important in some places but not others. Research experience can help. In some places you have an interview.

The idea is to build a picture of future expected success. Show you are on a trajectory to success.

But good grades are better than bad or mediocre grades, of course.